# Auto complete Java by pressing space bar in NetBeans or Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, autocomplete

How to set Eclipse or NetBeans to auto complete code by pressing "Space" bar only

like Visual Studio 2015 or MonoDevelop(Unity built-in)?

(Java)

Comment: personally I think having only space bar can be very annoying and increases unintentional auto complete, eclipse uses ctrl+space for suggestion and enter to auto complete, its much better

Comment: @nafas I couldn't agree more. Like when you're writing `for(int i = 0;)` and the i turns into something stupid when you press space.

Answer (score 0):

To get the predictions shortcut is "CTRL" + "SPACE"